# using namespace: Convenience vs. namespace pollution

Tags: c++, templates, stl, namespaces

I'm writing a simple stopwatch template using `<chrono>`. Since these functions are in `std::chrono`, it would be convenient to write `using namespace std::chrono` to avoid bloating up my code lines. But since it's a template, the `std::chrono` would then be visible in all files which include the template.

What should I do in this situation? Do I have to pick one of the options, or is there a way to avoid the problems of both options?

Comment: Is your stopwatch template not in its own namespace?

Comment: So far, not. If I put it into `namespace stopwatch` and write `using namespace std::chrono` in that namespace would `std::chrono` be visible in file `using namespace stopwatch`? (I see, I should read some pages about namespaces...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a namespace alias in you code:

```
namespace bc = boost::chrono;
```

and use

```
bc::duration d;
```

You can put this alias inside the functions you need `boost::chrono` so they do not contaminate other code.

```
template<T>
class foo {
    void bar() {
        namespace bc = boost::chrono;

        bc::duration d;
    }

    // namespace alias bc is no longer in scope.
}
```

Alternatively, you can put the `using namespace` inside the scope of your template/function, however, I think this will reduce readability and will possibly cause conflicts between the `boost` and `C++11` `std` namespaces.

```
template<T>
class foo {
    void bar() {
        using namespace boost::chrono;

        duration d;
    }

    // using namespace boost::chrono is no longer in scope.
}
```

Comment: But I can not put the `namespace bc = boost::chrono?` just inside the class, right? (Compiler comes up with an error: `StopWatch.h(13): error: expected a declaration namespace chr = std::chrono;`
)